# how to set name of multiple textbox in openerp using qweb template engine?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

Here is my code:

```
<tr t-foreach="keyword" t-as="item"><td><t t-esc="item_value"/></td><td><input type="text" name=""/></td></tr>
```

So here, Textbox are generated dynamically.

Now I want to set textbox name to the value that is generated on

```
<t t-esc="item_value"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the text box name to item_value you need to use the t-att attribute:

```
<input type="text" t-att-name="item_value"/>
```

Hope this helps!