# How to set colspan value from function in qWeb?

Tags: odoo

I am trying to make an HTML report using qWeb in Odoo. Table I have to print has variable columns, and those columns have variable colspan values, so I defined a method in Python in order to return the header and colspan of that columns. Method returns something like this:

```
OrderedDict({'header 1' : 6, 'header 2' : 6, 'header 3' : 2, 'resume' : 2})
```

In qWeb code I wrote this:

```
<td align="center" style="border:1px solid black;" colspan="<t t-esc='partial_value' />" ><b><t t-raw="partial" /></b></td>
```

The name of the column (the header) is printed successfully, but the colspan value is raising an exception (XMLSyntaxError: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values). I also tried tag t using t-esc... It raised same error.

So, how to set colspan value dynamically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

possible duplicate of [how to set name of multiple textbox in openerp using qweb template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778744/how-to-set-name-of-multiple-textbox-in-openerp-using-qweb-template-engine/26766760#26766760)

in your case you would put:

```
<td align="center" style="border:1px solid black;" t-att-colspan="resume">
```

Hope this helps.